# Context menu on Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I have a context menu in a DataTrigger on treeview? The code below does not trigger the context menu eg I want the menu on "Symbols" as well. Although I have a context menu on HierarchicalDataTemplate which works fine but only on child elements. The root on the treeview does not have a menu

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildPlanner}">
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style>
          <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFolder}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource AddNewSymbol}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold">
     </TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView Name="SymbolsTreeView">
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFolder}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource AddNewSymbol}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <TreeViewItem Header="Symbols" IsExpanded="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PlannerTreeList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"/>
</TreeView>
```

Imagine my tree is

```
Symbols
  Current
    Menu1Folder
    Menu2Folder
      Menu2Item
      Menu2AnotherItem
    Current1Item
```

The HierarchicalDataTemplate's menu works for menu1folder onwards which is ok. But I want it to work for Current1Item, Current and Symbols. Since Current1Item is not a folder, there should be no menu for it but Current and Symbols are folders

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource AddNewSymbol}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFolder,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
       </DataTrigger>                                
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Do you have different DataTemplates for different object types of yours?

Comment: @Krishna Yes. I have two separate Itemsource. The  HierarchicalDataTemplate uses ChildPlannerList and the Treeview uses PlannerTreeList

Comment: I am still not sure how your layout is rendered. But see my answer and let me know if it any helpful. Otherwise please give more information about the hierarchy of your treeview and I (or someone else) might be able to help

Comment: Instead of Binding Header, use your Property IsFolder value = "False" to null the ContextMenu

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately does not work for me. I have updated my question with the treeview resource. I get context menu on folders as well as items

Comment: Sorry, if it is a property from your viewmodel you dont need the RelativeSource part, simply Binding={Binding IsFolder} Value="False" will do. Can you use a utility like Snoop and make sure the IsFolder is set to false on the items? Also you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModels right?

Comment: Sorry but still struggling. I have checked the value of IsFolder by adding a checkbox and I am definitely get the right value

Comment: Ok. Please check my edit and see how I am applying a visibility converter to the context menu instead of a datatrigger. Remove the datatrigger from the treeviewitem and use this converter instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit - Try this new code. I am using a converter to show and hide the contextmenu based on your property. It works with my sample code. Let me know if you want my sample code.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MenuOne" Visibility="{Binding IsFolder,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Add Folder" Command="{Binding AddFolderCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add Item" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView Name="SymbolsTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ContentControl>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </ContentControl>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MenuOne}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```